# Query document field and nested document field

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

MongoDB is very complicated to query IMO.  Anyway...

I have the following document structure:

[image: Document structure]

I would like to return a result where the `t` field matches "99CalcTrigger" and the date equals `vdata.d`.

I have the following so far:

```
var results = from q in collection.AsQueryable()
                          from value in q.valueData
                          where q.t == "99CalcTrigger" && value.d == "2018-12-09T04:40:00Z"
                          select q;
```

This returns an error when I perform a `foreach` loop on results:

> System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support
>   {document}.'

Any ideas?

Here is the class I am using:

```
public class Tag
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("t")]
    public string t { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("e")]
    public string e { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("desc")]
    public string desc { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("d")]
    public string d { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("vdata")]
    public List<Vdata> valueData { get; set; }


}

public class Vdata
{
    [BsonElement("t")]
    public string t { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("q")]
    public string q { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("d")]
    public string d { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your class which is used to represent data stored in collection ?

Comment: @mickl Class added as requested